# "print 1 to n" function prints 1 twice

Tags: c++, recursion

```
 void printInt(int n){
   if(n==1)
     cout<<1<<" ";
   else
     printInt(n-1);
     cout<<n<<" ";
  }
```

the output I get is

```
 1 1 2 3....n
```

I'm writing out the actual steps of the function on a piece of paper but I don't get how it is printing an extra 1 in the console (Visual Studio 2010). This is from past HW solutions so this is strictly for understanding how it works.

Comment: You can use `printInt( --n )` instead of `printInt( n - 1 )`

Comment: @olevegard, that will make the program not work as intended, so I don't think it's a very good change.

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @CarlNorum, ahh, of course, commented too quickly. But it would work if he swapped the two bottom lines.

Comment: if you are starting with c++ (also other c like syntax languages)  you always should use all braces, even if it is an one-liner.

Answer (score 9):

You need some braces:

```
   if(n==1)
   {
     cout<<1<<" ";
   }
   else
   {
     printInt(n-1);
     cout<<n<<" ";
   }
```

Or else the second `cout` gets run even when `n==1`.  Strictly speaking the braces around the *first* `cout` aren't required, but I like it for style in this case.

Editorial note:  This problem could be easily solved by stepping through your function in a debugger.

Comment: thanks, I can't believe I forgot to put in braces for the else clause, I feel really stupid but thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do not enclose an if-else statements in braces it only executes the line directly after it. So in your case the line `printInt(n-1);` is the only line inside the else statement (in the eye of the compiler).

To avoid problems like this, enclose the whole statement in braces:

```
void printInt(int n){
   if(n==1)
   {
       cout<<1<<" ";
   }
   else
   {
       printInt(n-1);
       cout<<n<<" ";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in C++ indentation is not used so your code means indeed

```
void printInt(int n){
   if(n==1)
     cout<<1<<" ";
   else
     printInt(n-1);
   cout<<n<<" ";
}
```

so the `cout << n << " "` is outside the check.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printInt(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        printInt(n - 1);
        cout << n << " ";
    }
}
```